# Что делает оператор "..."?

Tags: golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего нужен оператор "..." (предпоследняя строка кода)

```
func Sort(input []int) []int {
    l := len(input)
    if l < 2 {
        return input
    }
    less := make([]int, 0)
    bigger := make([]int, 0)
    pivot := input[0]
    for _, v := range input[1:] {
        if v > pivot {
            bigger = append(bigger, v)
        } else {
            less = append(less, v)
        }
    }
    input = append(Sort(less), pivot)
    input = append(input, Sort(bigger)...)
    return input
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор позволят распаковывать слайс

Вместо:

```
ss := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
var newSs []int

for _, num := range ss {
    newSs = append(newSs, num)
}
```

Вы можете написать

```
ss := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
var newSs []int
newSs = append(newSs, num...)
```

Проще говоря аналог: `append(newSs, num[0], num[1], num[2], ..., num[N])`, тк вы не можете не знать число элемнтов (может быть 1, а может быть 10500), а надо все туда заапендить какие есть

Если перейдете в декларацию функции append(), то увидите что она принимает с таким же оператором неопределенное число элементов

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за помощь!